# PHP Error Logs in Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, error-logging

I have a PHP app deployed on Heroku, but I can't seem to locate the apache error log. Using the command `$heroku logs` I seem to get only the apache access logs. So a bunch of GET 200 OK etc, but no error information that is put into the error log locally, such as 'PHP Fatal error: *blah blah*'

Where do I access these error logs on Heroku, or how do I tell the app to write to Heroku's log like it does the local error log?

I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: was wondering this myself. Please give an answer if you've found out.

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of experimentation, it looks like you need to comment out `error_log` in php.ini 
and make sure `log_errors = on` .. this should output your errors to stderr where the heroku logplex can pick up the stream, then monitor with `heroku logs --tail` .. I launched a heroku facebook app and looked at their phpinfo() and copied the setup.

Comment: In you opinion so I just need to set `log_errors = On` in my php.ini? It doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

To the very top of your PHP page/app

Comment: Really? I see this in my log:

"Wed Feb 06 18:51:35 2013] [error] [client 10.44.51.101] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /app/www/index.php on line 5"

Is that not what the OP wanted?

Comment: The test code is just:

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

obvious error here
?>

I deploy to Heroku, no config changes - and the run heroku logs after hitting index.php.

Comment: @joshbirk's code works for me - I get `2013-02-07T18:12:14+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thu Feb 07 18:12:14 2013] [error] [client 10.92.74.179] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /app/www/index.php on line 1` in my Heroku log.

Comment: This actually looks like the easiest approach, since it requires no ini file or buildpack hacking - just set it in some PHP file that everything includes.

Answer (score 1):

We had to add this to our buildpack in the bin/compile file:

```
cat >>boot.sh <<EOF
for var in \`env|cut -f1 -d=\`; do
  echo "PassEnv \$var" >> /app/apache/conf/httpd.conf;
done
touch /app/apache/logs/error_log
touch /app/apache/logs/access_log
touch /app/apache/logs/php_error.log
tail -F /app/apache/logs/error_log &
tail -F /app/apache/logs/access_log &
tail -F /app/apache/logs/php_error.log &
echo "Launching apache"
exec /app/apache/bin/httpd -DNO_DETACH
EOF
```

We left the php.ini and https.conf settings mostly as-is.

Answer (score 0):

That is not related to Heroku way of deploying, but to your PHP configuration. The [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) directive manages that.

The `error_log` directive defines the name of the file where script errors should be logged. The file should be writable by the web server's user.

Answer (score 0):

I my laravel project I achieve see the errors by issue

heroku config:set APP_DEBUG=true

Acess app again and the errors will showed in browser