# Removing FreeType from XAMPP Apache

Tags: php, apache, config, freetype

I have this problem that the server I have to work on doesn't have FreeType installed, and local testing won't show up if the library I've used actually uses it or not (neither does the server, since logs are turned off). Is there any way to disable FreeType in my local apache version?

Comment: There is, but are you sure it is necessary? Not sure what problem it is causing?

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to show a (strictly gd-only) chart on a heroku&PHP based site (PHPInfo: http://phpinfo.herokuapp.com/) which doesn't support sooo many things. I can't tell what's wrong, since it works on my side perfectly. On serverside, it's just an empty white screen with no errors :/

Comment: Then the first step should probably be [turning on error reporting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/how-do-i-enable-error-reporting-in-php)

Comment: Error reporting seems to be hardcoded to be disabled - I changed all the php.ini files to turn it on, included the error reporting script in the headers of the files, nothing helps :/

Comment: Check out [PHP Error Logs in Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13772505)