# PHP error logs in Heroku are not displayed

Tags: php, heroku, error-logging

I have a question which is a copy of [PHP Error Logs in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772505/php-error-logs-in-heroku).

Unfortunately, none of the suggested answers worked.

I have `log_errors = On`and `error_log = "c:/wamp64/logs/php_error.log"` (commented out). Using the command `heroku logs` return a status code of 500 but no error(s) is/are displayed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If your error_log line is commented out you probably arent saving errors

Comment: Can you please explain? when I'm working locally, they are saved in php_error.log